# How can I create a table with five foreign keys and one of them as primary key (which is also a VARCHAR)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to create a table like,

```
    USE [labblyDabbly3455]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[daTableBang]
    (
     TableAID varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(ID)
     TableATitle VarChar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(title)
     TableAName varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(Name)
     TableASurName varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(surname)
     TableBID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableB(ID)
    )
```

but getting error,

> Incorrect syntax

I need to declare TableAID as primary key too, **can someone help me with syntax plz**

After i try voo answer i get this error,

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'TableB' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK__0A537D18'.

Comment: where is you primary key you mentioned?

Comment: You're missing commas. And declaring 4 columns each of which can only contain no or 1 character. And all of the columns are nullable. Is that really what you want? (Nullable columns can't be part of the primary key)

Comment: @Borsel I don't know how I can declare a primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add commas in your CREATE query after each column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[daTableBang]
(
 TableAID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(ID),
 TableATitle VarChar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(title),
 TableAName varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(Name),
 TableASurName varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(surname),
 TableBID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableB(ID)
)
```

Also I recommend you to change the stucture by making TableAID and TableBID as a primary key, and TableAID as a foreign key to table A, and TableBID as a foreign key to table B. And to remove TableATitle, TableAName, TableASurName of caurse. And the result query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[daTableBang]
(
 TableAID int not null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(ID),    
 TableBID int not null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableB(ID),
 PRIMARY KEY (TableAID,TableBID)
)
```

Comment: He's also likely to have trouble with four separate foreign key references to TableA.  I doubt that Name, Surname, and title are all UNIQUE keys.

Comment: @voo how can I make TableAID and TableBID primary key in above query, thank you

Comment: *"Yes, but that is logical error, not RDBMS. The query should work."* No, it probably shouldn't. SQL Server requires that foreign keys target columns that have a unique constraint.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Yes, it shouldn't :) The TableA should have ID as PK, and TableB should have ID as PK. This would make the second query to work.